# I can`t decide what to select: ASP.NET MVC 2 (C#) or Django (Python)?

Tags: c#, python, django, asp.net-mvc-2

I`m learning programming languages. And I decide that I need to lear a new web framework. I have 2 candidates: Django or ASP.NET MVC 2.

Can you say me the difference between them and what is so interesting?

Comment: Do you have any skills with C# and/or Python? How about some other web frameworks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try both, then decide.

Comment: Expanding on this:  If your base skills are roughly even, making the learning curve the same for both, do a quick prototype in both and make your call from there.

Comment: I think this is the best answer, really. If you HAVE the time, I'd say write a simple spec for a blog, and use that to learn your web frameworks. can't hurt to know a bit about both!

Comment: Ok, i'll do it. I'll try both of them.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I'm using both and found both to be state of the art, easy to learn, fast and easy to install.

Maybe don't look at it from a technical standpoint but from the context. ASP.NET needs a Windows Server, ASP.NET and an IIS installed. You have the license for that? Django on the other hand is open source runs on cheap but fast linux machines and provides you with the Python Language and it's vast easy to install moduls.

If you don't know Python or C# maybe Django is the better way to go. Djangos Documentation is great and has a great tutorial, which is yet to be found on the ASP.NET MVC side.

Well, the conclusion is: Try both :) And if you're gonna use ASP.NET MVC, watch the Nerddinner Sessions (PDC) by Scott Hanselman and Phil Haack.

Comment: Notice that you can use ASP.NET MVC with Mono (so without Windows & IIS). Also, it works :)

Answer (score 1):

I would create a small app to try each for a day or two and then choose.

I can't speak for Django, but here are some Asp.Net MVC benefits

1. Tight integration with other Microsoft technologies
2. Uses jquery out of the box
3. Choice of several server-side languages
4. Very flexible (choice of unit test framework, view engine, model architecture etc)

and a potential negative

1. Might take extra work getting it running on anything other than Windows

Answer (score 1):

- What reasons lead you to choose those
  two frameworks?
- What reasons lead you to choose those
  two languages?

If you don't like the answers, then keep looking.  Otherwise...

- Do you want to be on a
  non-Microsoft web stack?  Go Django.
- Do you want to interface with lots of other
  Microsoft web stack technologies?  Go
  MVC.
- Do you want complied language speed?  Go C#.
- Do you want interpreted language portability? Go Python.